# sum field with GROUP BY fails

Tags: mysql

I have a very nasty query. I try to get a classification table sorted by touchdowns... But before reaching that goal I have a problem with a sum... let me explain.

With this query:

```
SELECT tft.id_team
     , z.id_partido
     , y.td 
  FROM `team_faseTorneo` tft
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT j.id_fase
            , tp.id_team
            , tp.id_partido 
         FROM jornadas j 
         LEFT 
         JOIN partidos USING(id_jornada) 
         JOIN team_partido tp USING(id_partido)
     ) z 
    ON z.id_fase = tft.id_fase 
   AND z.id_team=tft.id_team
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT p.id_team
            , pL.id_partido
            , pL.td 
         FROM players p 
         JOIN playerLogros pL USING(id_player)
     ) y 
    ON y.id_team = tft.id_team 
   AND y.id_partido = z.id_partido
 WHERE tft.id_fase = 4
```

The result is this one:

```
id_team id_partido  td
6   69  0
6   69  0
6   69  0
6   69  0
6   81  0
6   81  0
6   81  0
6   81  1
6   84  1
6   84  0
6   98  NULL
6   99  NULL
6   114 NULL
6   116 NULL
6   129 NULL
6   133 NULL
6   144 NULL
6   150 NULL
6   159 NULL
6   167 NULL
19  72  0
19  72  0
19  77  2
19  77  0
19  77  1
19  77  0
19  77  0
19  89  0
19  89  0
19  92  NULL
```

NUll is for the matchs(partidos) not played yet. I need to sum all the touchdowns scored by match (partido), so I tried this:

```
SELECT tft.id_team,z.id_partido, y.td FROM `team_faseTorneo` tft
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT j.id_fase, tp.id_team, tp.id_partido FROM jornadas j LEFT JOIN partidos USING(id_jornada) JOIN team_partido tp USING(id_partido)
) z ON(z.id_fase=tft.id_fase AND z.id_team=tft.id_team) LEFT JOIN(SELECT p.id_team, pL.id_partido, SUM(pL.td) td FROM players p JOIN playerLogros pL USING(id_player) GROUP BY p.id_team) y ON(y.id_team=tft.id_team AND y.id_partido=z.id_partido) 
WHERE tft.id_fase=4
```

But the result is this:

```
id_team id_partido  td
6   69  NULL
6   81  NULL
6   84  NULL
6   98  NULL
6   99  NULL
6   114 NULL
6   116 NULL
6   129 NULL
6   133 NULL
6   144 NULL
6   150 NULL
6   159 NULL
6   167 NULL
19  72  3
19  77  NULL
19  89  NULL
19  92  NULL
19  106 NULL
```

How Can I solve this?
Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: What should the result be? Although, if it was me, I'd have separate tables for fixtures and results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a sum, then use an aggregation query.  Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT tft.id_team, z.id_partido, SUM(y.td)
FROM `team_faseTorneo` tft LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT j.id_fase, tp.id_team, tp.id_partido
       FROM jornadas j LEFT JOIN
            partidos
            USING (id_jornada) JOIN
            team_partido tp
            USING (id_partido)
      ) z
      ON z.id_fase=tft.id_fase AND z.id_team=tft.id_team LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT p.id_team, pL.id_partido, pL.td td
       FROM players p JOIN
            playerLogros pL
            USING (id_player)
      ) y
      ON y.id_team=tft.id_team AND y.id_partido=z.id_partido
WHERE tft.id_fase = 4
GROUP BY tft.id_team, z.id_partido;
```

Your query seems overly complicated, but this should at least get you the sum of `td`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I got it...

```
SELECT tft.id_team,z.id_partido, sum(z.td) FROM `team_faseTorneo` tft
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT j.id_fase, tp.id_team, tp.id_partido, y.td FROM jornadas j LEFT JOIN partidos p USING(id_jornada) JOIN team_partido tp USING(id_partido) LEFT JOIN(SELECT p.id_team, pL.id_partido, (pL.td) td FROM players p JOIN playerLogros pL USING(id_player) ) y ON(y.id_team=tp.id_team AND y.id_partido=tp.id_partido)  WHERE p.status='Finalizado' 
) z ON(z.id_fase=tft.id_fase AND z.id_team=tft.id_team) 
WHERE tft.id_fase=4 GROUP BY tft.id_team, z.id_partido ORDER BY tft.id_team
```